# Evaluating pytorch pretrained model using a single image from a dataset

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Could someone help me in this problem: I try to evaluate pretraining an image with a ML model and i reveive the error state in the bottom of this post.

As I understand the pytorch model want data to be in the following format: batch_channel, channel, Height, Lenght. I modify the tensor to be in this shape but I still get that Error.

Can someone explain to me why does this error occurs?

I am very new to coding and ML, so I am sorry if this question is not very specific.

```
from monai.transforms import AddChannel
from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
import cv2
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import models


img_array = imread(train_imageinfo_list[0][0])


resized_img = cv2.resize(img_array, (224, 224))
img_tensor = torch.from_numpy(resized_img)
channel_adder = AddChannel()
channel_image = channel_adder(img_tensor)
batch_image = channel_adder(channel_image)
img_tensor = batch_image
model= models.vgg16()
model(img_tensor)
eval(model)
```

> ERROR: RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [64, 3, 3, 3], expected input[1, 1, 224, 224] to have 3 channels, but got 1 channels instead

Comment: Are you inferring with a grayscale input?

Comment: Yes I am trying to analyze a chest x-ray image which is black and white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model expects a 3-channel input, that's why you are getting an error. A naive and straightforward approach is to convert your grayscale image to rgb by repeating the channel dimension three times:

```
>>> x = img_tensor.repeat(1,3,1,1) # assuming img_tensor shaped BCHW
>>> y = model(x)
```